Expo web view implementation into a pre existing react native expo project
I have an existing react native expo project. I’ve tried installing and using expo-web-view with no success. I’m trying to incorporate an iframe with a Soundcloud widget into the expo react native project. At the moment nothing shows up.
import { WebView } from 'expo-web-view';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <WebView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      url="https://expo.dev"
      onLoad={event => alert(`loaded ${event.nativeEvent.url}`)}
    />
  );
}

I’ve followed the exact instructions from the docs: https://docs.expo.dev/modules/native-view-tutorial/#1-initialize-a-new-module
